# Shifting table view position and hiding views

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uitextfield, uisearchbar

My design consists of a search bar at the top and then a table view below. However, there is a nuance that requires me to display  an image and a label to below the search bar and above the table if the user clicks on the search bar text field. I was thinking of setting the the view containing the label and the image as hidden and then moving the table's frame depending of if the user has started editing/typing in the search text field. But I wasn't sure if this was the best way of doing it and if this was a good idea? Any code would be helpful.

Essentially I want to know how to hide a view and then moving my tableview to be in the exact same position without the gap or blank whitespace being shown.

Comment: You could also create the view when the user starts editing/typing instead of unhiding it. But that's just another way of doing it. Post what you have done till now to help you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please do it.. I think it may be your help.

```
    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        // here you make your image and label hidden and change your tableview's frame means table's y coordinte.

       Like that 
       lbl.hidden     = YES;
       imgView.hidden = YES;

       tblview.frame = CGRectMake

(tblView.frame.origin.x,50,tblView.frame.size.width,tblView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: the issue is That when I move my table up using CGRectMake, the table is not able to be in that position ( I think because the view exists in storyboard.

Comment: Yes, Its a problem . You also know my code will work in normal view.So i've written here.I don't know more about storyboard dear.So sorry dear.

Answer (score 0):

Use following delegate methods to detect search bar edit status

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar; 
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

In this method you can implement code to show/hide your view who contains Label And Image.

Then you have to set frame of your table view.

Comment: Thanks but when adjust the frame of my tableview it can't be in the same position As my hidden view.  How do I get around this?

Comment: If parent view for your both table view and other view  is same  then you can get x and y point from your detail view frame.Use this points to set position of your table view.

Comment: Yes, the parent view is the same. What do you mean when you say detail view frame?The issue is that when I hide the view with the label, the tableview is unable to take its exact position and the blank gap is always visible.

Comment: Detail view is view which contains label and image.